# Joomla 1.5 Cannot Access Files Directory

Tags: web-services, web, joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.5

Can you please advise how can I access my full files directory in Joomla 1.5.18?

I just need to remove some harmful files but I cannot find them. The hosting provider waits me to do that so that they can restore my full website public hosting.

Thanks!

Comment: Check with your hosting provider whether they are stll there, because you cannot find them.

Comment: Hi miroxlav, they have asked me to remove them myself. I have administrator access but the website was made years ago by a developer that we cannot track. For example, I can access media files but I cannot find files such as: /home/public_html/index.php or /home?public_html/libraries/phputf8/list.php

Comment: I meant, that if you can't find file `/home/public_html/index.php`, maybe there is a chance it is gone now. Could you ask your web provider to re-check the list of harmful files? Maybe you can invoke the re-check also by yourself from site control panel provided by your hosting provider. In my hosting, this is possible.

Comment: You are really using Joomla 1.5.18? This is very old and no longer secure and by the way might also cause that some "strange files" can be seen on the server. So please consider an update right now!